# Is there a programmatically accessible/structured (JSON, XML, etc) dictionary that includes IPA

Tags: english, computational-linguistics, ipa, dictionary

Thus far I have the CMU Pronouncing Dictionary, which uses a custom set of [phonemes represented in ASCII text](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict). Just the words and pronunciations is nice, but it would be great to have actual IPA pronunciations as well as definitions, parts of speech, synonyms, etc.

Any good places to start?

Comment: I suggest converting the ARPAbet representation into IPA. It should work automatically (e.g., using sed, perl, or python)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out one can [download Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Help:FAQ#Downloading_Wiktionary) and that has SQL database dumps. That has all the information I want (including IPA).